# How to Store Audio into buffer and then reading it byte by byte

Tags: android

I can make wav file by MediaRecord of android ...but I am interested to put the audio data in a buffer and read it byte by byte...I have to send audio chunks byte wise over TCP channel....Can any one help me please...thanks in advance,

szaman from austria

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AudioRecord` to read the audio data byte by byte, here is some sample code.

```
// calculate the minimum buffer
int minBuffer = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT);

// initialise audio recorder and start recording
AudioRecord mRec = new AudioRecord(AUDIO_SOURCE, SAMPLE_RATE, 
                CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT, 
                minBuffer);
mRec.startRecording();
byte[] pktBuf = new byte[pktSizeByte];
boolean ok;
// now you can start reading the bytes from the AudioRecord
while (!finished) {
    // fill the pktBuf
    readFully(pktBuf, 0, pktBuf.length);
    // make a copy
    byte[] pkt = Arrays.copyOf(pktBuf, pktBuf.length);
    // do anything with the byte[] ...
}
```

Since a single call to `read()` might not get enough data to fill the `byte[] pktBuf`, we might need to read multiple times to fill the buffer. In this case, I use an auxiliary function "readFully" to ensure the buffer is filled. Depending what you want to do with your code, different strategy can be used...

```
/* fill the byte[] with recorded audio data */
private void readFully(byte[] data, int off, int length) {
    int read;
    while (length > 0) {
        read = mRec.read(data, off, length);
        length -= read;
        off += read;
    }
}
```

Remember to call `mRec.stop()` to stop the `AudioRecorder` after finished. Hope that helps.